# Updating the view on Android Studio when the Firebase data is changed

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently developing an app that displays all repository data in a listView. In my fragment, I call a function called fetchRepoData that fetches the data from the Firebase DB and puts into a listView.

**OnCreateView**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.repo_result_tab, container, false);

        repoListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.repoList_result);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        sortByNameRadio = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sort_by_name);
        sortByRelevanceRadio = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sort_by_relevance);

        repoListItems = new ArrayList<>();
        repoNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        userNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        descriptionList = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new RepoListAdapter(getContext(), repoListItems);
        repoListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        repoReference = Database.child("Repo Search Results");
        .....
```

**fetchRepoData**

```
private void fetchRepoData(String profileUserID) {

    profileUserDatabase = repoReference.child(profileUserID);

    //DatabaseReference reposReference = profileUserDatabase.child("Repos");

    profileUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                repoNameList.add(snapshot.getValue(RepoInfo.class).getRepoName());
                userNameList.add(snapshot.getValue(RepoInfo.class).getOwner());
                descriptionList.add(snapshot.getValue(RepoInfo.class).getDescription());
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < repoNameList.size(); i++) {
                repoListItems.add(new RepositoryItem(i, repoNameList.get(i), userNameList.get(i), descriptionList.get(i)));
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

However, whenever I try to update the data in my Firebase, the listView does not update and remains the same. The Toast message "changed" appears, but the view remains the same even though I remove an item from the list.

I also tried putting

```
repoListItems.clear();
```

inside the onDataChange, but it didn't work.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well my advice for you is to use Firebase UI to do so.

Its an easy and efficient way to update either a list view or a recyclerview ui.

You can find more details here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: By the way, you say you deleted item but it didn't removed from the list. For it to be removed you need to remove it from the adapter, you only managed a case where you added item.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be problem with adapter, It is not refreshing the items.
    You can write a function in adapter ie

```
  public void swapItems(ArrayList<String> repoListItems) {
            this.repoListItems = itemList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

change your code like below:

     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        repoNameList.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    repoNameList.add(snapshot.getValue(RepoInfo.class).getRepoName());
                    userNameList.add(snapshot.getValue(RepoInfo.class).getOwner());
                    descriptionList.add(snapshot.getValue(RepoInfo.class).getDescription());
                }

        for(int i = 0; i < repoNameList.size(); i++) {
            repoListItems.add(new RepositoryItem(i, repoNameList.get(i), userNameList.get(i), descriptionList.get(i)));
                }
            adapter.swapItems(repoNameList);
            }
```

Note: I have read the above from stackoverflow only, but i didn't find the link to post here.